# iOS: deliver NSLocalNotification or Push Notification only when user is idle

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to send a notification to the user of my iOS application, preferably using NSLocalNotificaiton.

However, if the user is on a call I don't want them to recieve the notification until after the call (I don't want to interrupt their call). Is there any way to schedule the notification to occur after the call has ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notification will no more interrupt a call than a calendar or SMS alert does—the alert view will appear on their screen, and if the ringer isn't silenced then the alert sound will play, but the user won't get disconnected or anything in the process. The only way you have of detecting that the user may have finished a call is the `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` method on your app delegate, but if your app's going to be in the foreground (which is the only point at which it'll receive that message) then you don't need to bother with a `UILocalNotification`. In short: no, you can't schedule things around the user's phone activity, but nor should you worry about your notifications interrupting them mid-call.

Comment: Unfortuantely, The Alert window does pop up, however in FaceTime calls this actually appears infront of the video view blocking the video until the user clicks on the alert.
I want to be able to notify them after their FaceTime has ended, so that the user can choose to go back to my application after the call.

Comment: Ah... nope, can't be done with the current SDK. Sorry. You can file an enhancement request at bugreport.apple.com for the functionality you need.